# Sharing layers over multiple pages in inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Recently Inkscape (v1.2) added multi page support. Is there a way to share layers over several pages. One example would be a background image which should be placed at all pages.
Of course one could just copy the image to all pages but in case the image is more complex one increases memory usage etc..

Also it would be quite interesting if one could link layers to pages. Meaning that Layer "A" is exported to paged 1 and Layer "B" exported to page 2.

Answer (score 0):

Pages in inkscape are implemented as a set of viewports to a single SVG document.

You can check the current functionality [in the wiki](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/Multipage), or extra details from the main contributor Martin Owens YouTube channel.

In order to reuse features in all pages without inflating the document, I suggest you have a look at clones, which are references to a single object (or group).

If you want different layers on different pages, you may add as many layers as you want, and arrange them in a tree structure, so each page has contents on its own dedicated layers.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to the clone feature. So far never realized that Inkscape is capable of this. Together with the tree structure of layers the question is solved. But I would n ot call it "The most elegant solution".